# Align right input and left label

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I want to align label on left and input on right : 
I tried :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="" style="float: left;font-size: 20px;padding-right: 10px;">ID : </label>
            <input style="float:right" type="text" id="" name="" value="" placeholder="Id" class="form-control"  /> 
</div>
```

But not work this feature. Help me please!!!

Comment: working fine in chrome https://jsfiddle.net/ac7qvpL7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8069/)**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" id="" name="" value="" placeholder="Id" class="form-control"  /> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for CSS...

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="test">ID : </label>
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test">
</div>
```

Just remove `style="float: right;` from input...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have to use text-align="right" in place of float:right.Here is the right code:

```
 <div class="form-group">  
    <label class="control-label" for="" style="float: left;font-size: 20px;padding-right: 10px;">ID : </label>  
    <input style="text-align:right" type="text" id="" name="" value="" placeholder="Id" class="form-control"  /> 
</div>
```

Comment: 1. You are using bootstrap so can also use this:

     <form class="form-horizontal">  <br/>   
          <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
                   <input id="inputEmai`enter code here`l3" class="form-control text-right" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
             </div> 
        </form>

Answer (score 0):

i didnt get what you mentioned but upon my intuition suggesting this

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="demo" style="float: left;font-size: 20px;padding-right: 10px;">ID : </label>
            <input type="text" id="demo" name="" value="" placeholder="Id" class="form-control"  /> 
</div>
```

if this is not your requirement could you please elaborate the question.